# OpenCV crop function fatal signal 11

Tags: android, opencv, crop

Hello I am doing an android app which uses OpenCV to detect rectangles/squares, to detect them I am using functions (modified a bit) from squares.cpp. Points of every square found I am storing in vector> squares, then i pass it to the function which choose the biggest one and store it in vector theBiggestSq. The problem is with the cropping function which code i will paste below (i will post the link to youtube showing the problem too). If the actual square is far enough from the camera it works ok but if i will close it a bit in some point it will hang. I will post the print screen of the problem from LogCat and there are the points printed out (the boundaries points taken from theBiggestSq vector, maybe it will help to find the solution).

```
void cutAndSave(vector<Point> theBiggestSq, Mat image){
    RotatedRect box = minAreaRect(Mat(theBiggestSq));
    // Draw bounding box in the original image (debug purposes)
    //cv::Point2f vertices[4];
    //box.points(vertices);
    //for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    //{
    //cv::line(img, vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % 4], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, CV_AA);
    //}
    //cv::imshow("box", img);
    //cv::imwrite("box.png", img);
    // Set Region of Interest to the area defined by the box
    Rect roi;
    roi.x = box.center.x - (box.size.width / 2);
    roi.y = box.center.y - (box.size.height / 2);
    roi.width = box.size.width;
    roi.height = box.size.height;
    // Crop the original image to the defined ROI

    //bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(box.size.width / 2, box.size.height / 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Mat crop = image(roi);
    //Mat crop = image(Rect(roi.x, roi.y, roi.width, roi.height)).clone();
    //Utils.matToBitmap(crop*.clone()* ,bmp);
    imwrite("/sdcard/OpenCVTest/1.png", bmp);
    imshow("crop", crop);

}
```

[video of my app and its problems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quUJR3h9AzM)

[image]

cords printed respectively are: roi.x roi.y roi.width roi.height

Another problem is that the boundaries drawn should have a green colour but as you see on the video they are distorted (flexed like those boundaries would be made from glass?).

Thank you for any help. I am new in openCV doing it from only one month so please be tolerant.

EDIT:
drawing code:

```
//draw//
    for( size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++ )
    {
        const Point* p = &squares[i][0];
        int n = (int)squares[i].size();
        polylines(mBgra, &p, &n, 1, true, Scalar(255,255,0), 5, 10);
        //Rect rect = boundingRect(cv::Mat(squares[i]));
        //rectangle(mBgra, rect.tl(), rect.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2, 8, 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error basically tells you the cause - your ROI exceeds the image dimensions. This means that when you are extracting `Rect roi` from `RotatedRect box` then either x or y are smaller than zero, or the width/height pushes the dimensions outside the image. You should check this using something like

```
// Propose rectangle from data
int proposedX = box.center.x - (box.size.width / 2);
int proposedY = box.center.y - (box.size.height / 2);
int proposedW = box.size.width;
int proposedH = box.size.height;

// Ensure top-left edge is within image
roi.x = proposedX < 0 ? 0 : proposedX;
roi.y = proposedY < 0 ? 0 : proposedY;

// Ensure bottom-right edge is within image
roi.width = 
   (roi.x - 1 + proposedW) > image.cols ? // Will this roi exceed image?
   (image.cols - 1 - roi.x)               // YES: make roi go to image edge
   : proposedW;                           // NO: continue as proposed
// Similar for height
roi.height = (roi.y - 1 + proposedH) > image.rows ? (image.rows - 1 - roi.y) : proposedH;
```

Comment: So this should prevent of this error happening again or it is just to confirm 'width/height pushes the dimensions outside the image' ?

Comment: I've not tested it, but it should ensure that the roi is always within the image, no matter what box returns, and I believe that it is roi being outside the image that causes you error.

Comment: Ok thank you! i will try it now and post the results soon. One last thing: do you know why the boundaries of found rectangular/square are drawn are strange? Should be green but as you can see on video they are whiteish glassy something? (hard to describe).

Comment: Not sure, I can't see where you draw the rectangle in the code. You should be using the `cv::rectangle` function if that helps...

Comment: looks like your solution works now as now it goes to write file line of code! :) it is still something however it shows some problem according to save on SD card:

http://pastebin.com/AFqeu4uG
maybe this can save the iplimage only? not Mat?

Edited the post: added drawing code

Comment: I'm glad this solves your problem. However, I'm afraid I don't understand your second question, perhaps you could ask a separate about this issue and provide the relevant images and code?

Comment: I mean that i need some evidence that the square was cropped right (save the image on phones internal storage). Now it works (thanks to your solution, works as there is no crash but it would be good to get one sample of cropped picture). imwrite("/sdcard/OpenCVTest/1.png", bmp) does not even create the relevant folder for that :(

Comment: In the code above your cropped image is called `crop` not `bmp`, apart from that I'm not sure what doesn't work.

Comment: ok i will figure out it somehow:) according to your code (fixing cords) unfortunately still have this error but very rare. hmm